# How to get Google PlayStore country in Adobe Air

Tags: air, google-play, currency

We are having app that uses Milkmangames native extension for inApp purchases in Android app. The problem is that I can not find out the price and currency of the product user bought. Price from Google comes in localized format which is due to bad implementation at their side I guess. The price can be 5 dolars or 10 kroner, but it is impossible to know whether it is US dollars or Canadian dollars, Swedish kroner or Norway kroner.

Other option that would work for me is getting the market user is using, but I can not seem to find out the way to do it in AIR.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across almost the same issue trying to find a way to get the raw price data and country code so that we could track IAP data better. Apparently there is a long-standing feature request for the native Google IAB extension to support something like this: https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=93

Thankfully, AS3 itself provides an interface to get this information (as does native Android if you have your own ANE experience). Below is a sample in AS3 that should be able to get you what you want based on the information you get from the ANE in the localized price formatting.

```
var price:String = "$4.99";
var defaultLocaleID:LocaleID = new LocaleID(LocaleID.DEFAULT);
var currencyFormatter:CurrencyFormatter = new CurrencyFormatter(defaultLocaleID.name);
var currencyCode:String = currencyFormatter.currencyISOCode;
var currencySymbol:String = currencyFormatter.currencySymbol;
var priceClean:Number = currencyFormatter.parse(price).value;
trace( "CURRENCY TEST: price: " + price + " | currency code: " + currencyCode + " | symbol: " + currencySymbol + " | priceClean: " + priceClean );
```

The expected output for myself (in the US) is the below:

> CURRENCY TEST: price: $4.99 | currency code: USD | symbol: $ |
>   priceClean: 4.99

Hope that helps.